# HTTPS Node JS POST issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I'm using https for this POST request.

Could someone point out the issue here? I get undefined and no error message .

I tried wrapping the request before res.write with no success. I'm getting a

```
statusCode: 400
Bad Payload received by generic incoming webhook.
```

Thanks!

**connector.js**

```js
const https = require('https');

var dataString = {"text": "Hello World"};

const deets = {
    portal_trade_events: {
        host: "outlook.office.com",
        path: "/path",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': dataString.text.length
        }
    }
};

const options = {
    hostname: deets.portal_trade_events.host,
    port: 443,
    path: deets.portal_trade_events.path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: deets.portal_trade_events.headers
};



function post(options, data) {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            process.stdout.write(d)
        });
    });
    req.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error)
    });

    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    req.end()
    
}

post(options, dataString);
```

Comment: What is the HTTP status code that you get as response?

Comment: 400 - Bad Payload received by generic incoming webhook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, your headers for content-length look wrong. You're sending the full JSON, not just the one text value.

```
const https = require('https');

const data = JSON.stringify({
  text: 'Hello World'
});

const options = {
  hostname: 'outlook.office.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/path',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Comment: Still getting "statusCode: 400
Bad Payload received by generic incoming webhook."  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is an indication the contents of your request do not match what the service you are sending them to wants to receive. You should verify the contents of your JSON object in the body of your request.